# Восстановление виртуалки после нехватки памяти

Tags: linux, администрирование, virtualbox, boot, ядро

Есть виртуальная машина с виртуальным динамически увеличивающимся диском. При работе в гостевой ОС во время обновления закончилась память на хосте, пришлось выключать вм. Сейчас добавил памяти, но вм уже не грузится, а пишет

> file /vmlinuz-linux not found

Видимо, нехватка памяти произошла во время обновления ядра и новое ядро не записалось. Что можно сделать для восстановления файлов гостевой системы в данном случае? Если бы это была не виртуальная машина, то я бы загрузился с флешки и скопировал нужный файл, а как это сделать в VirtualBox?

Comment: Восстановите данные из бекапа.

Comment: при загрукзке выберете старое ядро

Comment: *Если бы это была не виртуальная машина, то я бы загрузился с флешки и скопировал нужный файл, а как это сделать в VirtualBox?* — точно так же: подключаете файл с загрузочным образом, указываете в настройках загружаться с него, и загружаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно точно так-же загрузиться с флешки на VirtualBox, загрузив iso файл в виртуальную машину и в BIOS через неё загрузиться.

Comment: постарайтесь сразу дать исчерпывающий ответ. вряд ли ведь вы будете отвечать на комментарии к этому вопросу, например, лет через десять.

Comment: _Если будут вопросы - спрашивайте_, в идеале развёрнутый ответ не вызывает доп. вопросов. Поэтому, раз вы так написали, то ваш ответ далёк от идеала.